# Exclusive datatypes in z3 (follow up)

Tags: z3, smt

I declared an exclusive datatype in z3 as well as a constant and a little assertion:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((IntOrBool (bpart (b Bool)) (ipart (i Int)))))
(declare-fun iob () (IntOrBool))    
(assert (= true (b iob)))
```

I get the expected result `(bpart true)`, but with

```
(assert (= 1 (i iob)))
```

z3 reports `(bpart false)`. 
Does z3 ignore the assertion I gave? If he treats the datatype as a non-exclusive one, how can I force z3 to return an `ipart` as result?

Comment: leave a comment if you downvote. Otherwise I do not understand how I should formulate the question, such that anyone understands it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions "b" and "I" are accessors. They can have arbitrary interpretations when applied to a constructor that does not match. So Z3 finds a model where iob is set to (bpart false) and (i (bpart false)) is interpreted as 1. You could force the right constructor by asserting instead:

```
 (assert (= (bpart true) iob))
```

or

```
(assert (= (ipart 1) iob))
```